# Как найти среднее время из массива времён?

Tags: массивы, delphi, время

Существует массив строк которые содержит в себе строковое представление времени.

```
var
  TimeArray: array [0..4] of string; // Массив из пяти элементов
begin
  TimeArray[0] := '08:00:00';
  TimeArray[1] := '12:30:45';
  TimeArray[2] := '15:15:30';
  TimeArray[3] := '18:45:20';
  TimeArray[4] := '22:10:55';
end;
```

Как найти среднее время из данного массива?

Comment: Уточните, в чем именно у вас затруднение?

Comment: @Kromster изучите мой ответ на данный вопрос, затруднение касается поиска "хорошей" реализации данной задачи, заместо моего топорного подхода.

Comment: В качестве учебного варианта - вполне годится. И даже комментариями снабдили 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как Шариков говорил - "взять всё, да поделить"

Перевести в `TDateTime` с помощью `StrToTime`, сложить времена и поделить на их количество, потом обратно `TimeToStr` (или другая функция форматирования). Это работает, потому что `TDateTime` - то же самое, что и `Double`, здесь я `Math.Mean` использовал:

```
var
  TimeArray: array [0..4] of string; // Массив из пяти элементов
  Times: array [0..4] of Double; // Массив из пяти элементов
  i: Integer;
  MeanTime: TDateTime;
begin
  TimeArray[0] := '08:00:00';
  TimeArray[1] := '12:30:45';
  TimeArray[2] := '15:15:30';
  TimeArray[3] := '18:45:20';
  TimeArray[4] := '22:10:55';
  for i := 0 to 4 do
    Times[i] := StrToTime(TimeArray[i]);
  MeanTime := Mean(Times);
  Caption := TimeToStr(MeanTime);
```

Comment: .. а если не хотите использовать `Mean`, то можно просто `avgTime: TDateTime; .. avgTime := 0; for i := 0 to 4 do avgTime := avgTime + StrToTime(TimeArray[i]) / 5; Caption := TimeToStr(avgTime);`

Answer (score 0):

Есть **топорный вариант** с переводом всё в секунды и обратно через `DecodeTime`, с последующим дивом на количество элементов.

```
var
  TimeArray: array [0..4] of string;
  TotalSeconds, AverageSeconds: Integer;
  Hours, Minutes, Seconds, MiliSeconds: word;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Заполняем массив временами
  TimeArray[0] := '08:00:00';
  TimeArray[1] := '12:30:45';
  TimeArray[2] := '15:15:30';
  TimeArray[3] := '18:45:20';
  TimeArray[4] := '22:10:55';

  // Инициализируем счетчики
  TotalSeconds := 0;

  // Проходим по массиву и суммируем все времена в секундах
  for i := 0 to 4 do
  begin
    // Преобразуем время из строкового формата в числовой
    DecodeTime(StrToTime(TimeArray[i]), Hours, Minutes, Seconds ,MiliSeconds);
    
    // Переводим все в секунды и суммируем
    TotalSeconds := TotalSeconds + (Hours * 3600) + (Minutes * 60) + Seconds;
  end;

  // Находим среднее время в секундах
  AverageSeconds := TotalSeconds div 5; // 5 - количество элементов в массиве

  // Теперь нужно преобразовать AverageSeconds обратно в формат чч:мм:сс
  Hours := AverageSeconds div 3600;
  Minutes := (AverageSeconds mod 3600) div 60;
  Seconds := (AverageSeconds mod 3600) mod 60;

  // Выводим среднее время
  ShowMessage(Format('%2.2d:%2.2d:%2.2d', [Hours, Minutes, Seconds]));
end;
```